# Laravel 5.2 deployement on filezilla

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-5

I have only the right to create my project under the /htdocs folder
I have /htodcs/mylaravel-project , I tried to modify the path in server.php file and removed the index.php and .htacess from /public to /htdocs/mylaravel-project and of course i changed the .env parameters
When I acess to the URL 'Erreur serveur 500' I Dont know why it's not working? I'm new to this , and i really need some help thank you

Answer (score 0):

don't remove index.php or .htaccess from public, just run `php artisan serve --port=8080` and go to url http://localhost:8080/

or start your server and go in browser to your public path

Comment: I'm not working on local !! I'm running my project on the server my url should be http://www.mywebsite.com/htdocs/mylaravel-project

Comment: Serveur : Localhost via UNIX socket
Type de serveur : MySQL
Version du serveur : 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Version du protocole : 10 !! I said maybe it's about the php version?? because normally laravel5.2 requires PHP >= 5.5.9

Comment: Yes, it is. PHP must be >= 5.5.9. Ant your address mywebsite.com/htdocs/mylaravel-project/public

Comment: still dont know how to run my project on my website :(

Comment: First of all upgrate php to 5.5.9 or higher

Comment: On local everything woks fine I have created my project and worked on it !! Now i'm trying to install it on the web server , But how can i upgrae php version of the web server??